# Xgboost on Spark Validation Indicator Column and Evaluation Metric

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am using the `xgboost PySpark API`. This API is experimental but it supports most of the features of the `xgboost API.`

As per the documentation below, `eval_set` parameter is not supported and instead, `validationIndicatorCol` parameter should be used.

1. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.spark
2. https://databricks.github.io/spark-deep-learning/#module-sparkdl.xgboost

   ```
   xgb = XgboostClassifier(featuresCol = "features", 
                           labelCol="label", 
                           num_workers = 40, 
                           random_state = 1,
                           missing = None, 
                           objective = 'binary:logistic',
                           validationIndicatorCol = 'isVal',
                           eval_metric = 'aucpr' ,
                           n_estimators = best_n_estimators, 
                           max_depth = best_max_depth, 
                           learning_rate = best_learning_rate       
                          )

    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vectorAssembler,xgb])
    pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(sampled_df)
   ```

It seems to be running without any errors which is great.

How do you print and look at the evaluation results? Traditional xgboost has `evals_result()` method which `pipelineModel.stages[-1].evals_result()` doesn't seem to work in the PySpark API. This method should normally work since the `PySpark API` documentation doesn't say otherwise. Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: I am attempting to do something similar, except with LightGBM (whose PySpark interface largely mirrors that of XGBoost for PySpark). I will let you know what I find.
One question for you: are you passing the 'isVal' column to the VectorAssembler as one of the inputCols, or no?

Comment: Is there LightGBM for PySpark? I didn't know that. Yes, the isVal column should be fed into the Vector Assembler